# Convert multiple pdf files to a CSV file

Tags: r, text, text-mining

My task is to convert all pdf files as shown in the figure 1 below into a single csv file.That is, one row in CSV file contains one pdf document. I use the following code and I am struggling. Your help and comment will be appreciated.

Thank you,

```
  # Convert multiple pdf files to CSV files before mining
  install.packages('pdftools')
  install.packages('xlsx')

  # Relevant libraries
  library("pdftools")
  library("xlsx")

  #Set up a path
  a<-"my path"
  folder<-list.files(path=a,pattern="pdf",full.name=TRUE)

 sapply(folder, FUN=function(i){
 file.rename(from=i,to =paste0(dirname(i),
                            "/",gsub(" ","",basename(i))))})

 folder1<-list.files(path=a,pattern="pdf",full.names=TRUE)  

 lapply(folder1, function(i) system(paste('"C:/Program 
 Files/xpdf/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE) )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain which part of code doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Hi PoGibas! I can convert only one pdf file to a text file, but what I would like to do is to convert all pdf files into a single csv file. In csv, each row contains only one pdf file. So, I do not know how to proceed to that stage.  Thank you.